# How to generate .sln/.vcproj using qmake

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4, qmake, vcproj

I have `main.cpp` in `c:\test` folder and do the following:

```
qmake -project
qmake -tp vc test.pro
```

The answer is:

```
WARNING: Unable to generate output for: C:/test//Makefile.Debug [TEMPLATE vcapp]
WARNING: Unable to generate output for: C:/test//Makefile.Release [TEMPLATE vcapp]
```

But, I don't need make files. I need .vcproj!

Environment: Windows XP Pro SP3, MSVC 7.1 and 8.0. Qt is installed in `C:\Qt\2010.02` (LGPL version). Commands are run from Qt Command Prompt.

What's wrong with it? How to generate .sln/.vcproj? May I generate them for MSVC 7.1 and 8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've installed bundle that doesn't support MSVC (MinGW only). Going to download [sources](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2.zip) and install Qt according to [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/install-win.html) and [that](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/deployment-windows.html).

Answer (score 28):

try using this from Qt command prompt and make sure you are in the same directory of the `.pro` file:

```
qmake -spec win32-msvc2008 -tp vc
```

if you are using VS2005, 2010, 2012, or 2013, replace `win32-msvc2008` with `win32-msvc2005`, `win32-msvc2010`, `win32-msvc2012`, or `win32-msvc2013`

Comment: i get only .vcxproj instead of .sln

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you use the following line :

qmake -tp vc Test.pro -o Test.vcproj

If you start a new project, I would really recommend you to test this scrits package... A friend of mine wrote them and they are excellent ! Take 10 minutes to read how to create them, and in no time, you'll have all the scripts you need to create PRO, VCPROJ and build in one command...

http://www.dprog.net/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=39:qt-integration-scripts&catid=32:qt-integration-scripts&Itemid=47

Comment: "qmake -tp vc Test.pro -o Test.vcproj" generated test.vcproj but this is not vcproj. It is just plain old Makefile with difference name :-(

Answer (score 0):

Most simple one
qmake -project
qmake -t vcapp

and you get the .vcproj file