# qmake TEMPLATE = subdirs visual studio project generation

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qmake, subdirectory

in my project I'm using in my "main" .pro file TEMPLATE = subdirs that includes other sub-projects(2 additional libraries + target executable). As an outcome I would like to have an application that is linked against those 2 libraries. Based on my pro files structure I would like to generate visual studio 2008 or 2010 project file as some people prefer visual studio than Qt Creator as their IDE. What I have tried was:

```
qmake -t vcapp -spec win32-msvc2008 main.pro
```

but it gives some kind of an empty visual project file. If I repeat the same step for all my subdir project everything is fine. Only creating "the main one" that should have sub-projects in dependencies is not working correctly. I'm using qmake that comes with qt 4.7.3 release on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate .sln/.vcproj using qmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339832/how-to-generate-sln-vcproj-using-qmake)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
qmake main.pro -tp vc -r
```