# QT 5.0.1 QMake does not make anything

Tags: qt, qmake

I am very new to Qt and I want to make a simple image editor.
So I downloaded 5.0.1 and I am inside Qt Creator, as far as I understand it lets you design the UI and build/run from within the editor.

I want to actually use the Visual Studio IDE as I am comfortable with it, so I assume I need to run qmake on my Qt project. It outputs that it has exited normally but I don't get any .sln files or .proj files anywhere, I only seem to get a vc100.pdb file in debug folder.

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/untitled
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# If your application uses the Qt Mobility libraries, uncomment the following
# lines and add the respective components to the MOBILITY variable.
# CONFIG += mobility
# MOBILITY +=

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

Comment: It might be easier to answer if we could see your untitled.pro file. Could you edit your question, and paste in the .pro file (formatted as code), in case it contains any clues, please? Thanks.

Comment: According to this [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2454273/104370), if you add `-tp vc` to your qmake command-line, it will generate .sln and related files. But the answers to use the Qt Visual Studio Add-in, if you can, are better ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an Visual Studio edition different than express, you can install the [VS add-in](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other) and you don't need to manually run *qmake* (or create projects, or create sln and project, you will still use an external designer application)

Comment: I installed the plugin for vs2012 but the qt version vs2010 I dont know if thats ok? It also fails to link: LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother yourself with qmake and other stuff, just [download Visual Studio Add-In](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other) which allows you to forget about these all problems. You just need to install one of these (depends on which Visual Studio you use), select path for your Qt binaries and enjoy :) After create new project all paths will be set and all what you need is to run option "Build project"